# help with structs and looping in C

Tags: c, struct

beginner in C here. Is this legal here? I keep getting status access violation when i run this code:

```
struct point {
    char *x;
    char *y;
}

int main()
{
    ....
    struct point *pt;

    for (;;)
    {
        ....        
        pt = process_message(message);
        printf("%s",pt->x);
        ...
    }
}

struct point* process_message(char* message)
{
    struct point *pt;
    pt = malloc(1*sizeof(struct point))
    strncpy(pt->x, message, 4);
    return pt;
}
```

**EDIT**

Hi guys i made some changes...but still getting the access violation. pls advise!

Comment: Show the code of `process_message`. As it stands now, you're using an uninitialized pointer...

Comment: We need more code to know where the error is.

Comment: `process_message` returns a pointer to `struct price`, however the variable `pt` is a pointer to `struct point`. Don't mix the types like that.

Comment: Also, why does `process_message` return a `struct price *` when you've written it and are using it like it returns a `struct point *`? (Also, you'll probably need to declare it _before_ you use it, and you may want to go ahead and define it then too, or perhaps define it in another file and declare it in a header.)

Comment: Sorry was code was sensitive so tried to convert to pseudo code..forgot to change price to point :P

Comment: @delita: Now you've allocated the point struct, but you haven't allocated the "x" and "y" `char *` strings. You must do the same thing and `malloc` those. You must then also be sure to `free` them. Your code snippet here is confusing and changing because you excerpted it. Please excerpt more clearly to begin with next time. :)

Answer (score 11):

You need to allocate memory for `struct point` in `process_message`.

Something like this:

```
struct point* process_message(char* message)
{
    struct point *pt;
    pt = malloc(1*sizeof(struct point));
    // ... do some processing ...
    return pt;
}
```

Of course, you should `free` the pointer at some point afterwards.

**Also you should return a `struct point` in `process_message` or check your type concordance.** If you look carefully, you will see you are returning a `struct price*` but you are expecting (on the calling side) a `struct point *`.

**UPDATE**:

Now that question was updated, you will also need to allocate memory for `char *x` and `char *y` **if** you want to do this:

```
strncpy(pt->x, message, 4);
```

I would recommend to read a little bit (or a lot) about memory management and pointers in C++. Pointers are not the only way of dealing with data in **C Programming Language**.

(NO ERROR CHECKING DONE FOR CODE SIMPLICITY)

Comment: Note that `pt->x` is also a pointer, and is used in a way that means it needs to point at something too.

Comment: @Steve: yes, OP just added that to the question.

Comment: @Pablo: Thanks for ur help! it all makes sense now!

Answer (score 5):

Your `main` function is OK. Your problem is in `process_message`, where you're using a pointer-to-a-struct but not allocating any memory for it, accessing it, then returning it. Declaring a pointer alone does not create the memory to hold the struct. So you should allocate (use `malloc` for example) the memory for the struct, so that the memory will "exist" after the end of the function. Then you can return the pointer to it as you're doing, and then you would `free` it in main when you were done with it.

There are possibly better ways to accomplish the goal here given the simple operation you're doing. One is to keep one "scratch" struct local in your `main` function, and pass its address to process message:

```
struct point pt;
process_message(message, &pt);
printf("%s", pt.x);
```

This will "Reuse" the local memory and not require the alloc/free. Notice here that you don't return anything, you just "fill in" the struct in the process function.

Finally, if you're using a modern version of C, you can actually just return the full structure from the function if you want:

```
struct point process_message(char* message)
{
    struct point pt;
    ... do some processing ...
    return pt;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
struct point pt = process_message(message);
```

Comment: (+1) I like your answer better. I think performance would hurt with a  `malloc` call inside `process_message` if called many, many, times.

Comment: You'd have to be using a truly antique version of C to run into problems returning structures.  That was allowed for a number of years before the C89 standard was published (though after K&R 1st Edn was published, which didn't allow it).

Answer (score 2):

Remember to allocate memory in the function `process_message`

```
pt = malloc (sizeof (struct point));
/* do processing */
return pt;
```

also after you have finished working with `pt` remember to free it `free (pt)`.

**EDIT**

Also you need to allocate the memory blocks to store the strings to `x` and `y` in the function, after allocation of the `pt`. When you have done working, you need to free the strings first (memory blocks) and then the structure.

Comment: I prefer to use `sizeof *pt`. When `pt` becomes a pointer to `struct price` there will be no need to change the malloc line :-)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create pointer, it's just a sizeof(ptr) memory , which points to some data. So you must have some memory where your data is stored.
So either allocate memory in your function ( process_message), or in calling function.
it should go like

```
struct point *pt = (struct point*)malloc(sizeof(struct point));
```

Comment: I prefer to use `sizeof *pt` (no need to cast the return value of malloc). When `pt` becomes a pointer to `struct price` there will be no need to change the malloc line :-)

Answer (score 0):

As written now, you're allocating the struct point, but that structure contains **pointers** to strings, and not storage for the strings themselves.  You need to allocate space for the strings before you copy into them:

```
pt = malloc(1*sizeof(struct point));
pt->x = (char *)malloc( strlen(message) + 1);
```

Don't forget to do the same for pt->y before you use it, and don't forget to separately free the storage allocated for the strings, and then that allocated for the struct.